# How to generate more than 1 sparkline with Vuetify sparkline component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify has a sparkline component that can be used to create simple graphs.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sparklines

I can't figure out how to add more than one sparkline in the same graph. Something like adding a second list of values to the component.

If there's no way, maybe some of you know a more suited graph tool that I could use with Vue.

```
<template>
  <v-sparkline
    :value="value"
    :gradient="gradient"
    :smooth="radius || false"
    :padding="padding"
    :line-width="width"
    :stroke-linecap="lineCap"
    :gradient-direction="gradientDirection"
    :fill="fill"
    :type="type"
    :auto-line-width="autoLineWidth"
    auto-draw
  ></v-sparkline>
</template>

<script>
  const gradients = [
    ['#222'],
    ['#42b3f4'],
    ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'],
    ['purple', 'violet'],
    ['#00c6ff', '#F0F', '#FF0'],
    ['#f72047', '#ffd200', '#1feaea'],
  ]

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      width: 2,
      radius: 10,
      padding: 8,
      lineCap: 'round',
      gradient: gradients[5],
      value: [0, 2, 5, 9, 5, 10, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 9, 0],
      gradientDirection: 'top',
      gradients,
      fill: false,
      type: 'trend',
      autoLineWidth: false,
    }),
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Right now vuetify supports only one value in array format, if we add 2d array, it wont accept, you can try vue chart js library to achieve the same

Answer (score 4):

In the code below, the first `sparkline` is attached normally to the `v-sheet`, while the second is stacked on top of the first `sparkline`.

```
<template>
  <v-sheet class="stackSheet" color="white">
    <v-sparkline
      :value="value1"
      color="blue"
      line-width="3"
      padding="10"
    ></v-sparkline>
    <v-sparkline
      class="stackSpark"
      :value="value2"
      color="red"
      line-width="3"
      padding="10"
    ></v-sparkline>
  </v-sheet>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      value1: [0, 2, 5, 9, 5, 10, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 9, 0],
      value2: [7, 4, 7, 2, 9, 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 7, 10, 1, 3, 5],
    }),
  }
</script>
<style lang="css" scoped>
.stackSheet {
    position: relative;
}
.stackSpark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
</style>
```